# Port forwarding not working

Tags: sql-server

i have an application that needs database(sql server 2008 r2) through public ip, so that the user can use his application anywhere.

i configured the router for port forwading,
i add the port and sql-browser in the firewall.

and when i try datasource = [publicIp]\SQLEXPRESS,1433 i can only access the server when im in the network..
but cannot access the server when im not in the network..and also cant ping the public ip..
i opened port 1433 already.

what seems to be the problem?

Comment: What's is your forward Port ? . If you use forward port on Router like 5678 to 1433 (SQLServer) , In Network you need use [publicIp]\SQLEXPRESS,5678  and Port 5678 will forward port to 1433 by your Router

Answer (score 0):

Port 1433 isn't enough. When you're running a different than default instance, it will run on a different port. Usually, SQL browser service would help you find it, but you have to forward all the relevant ports as well, which is quite unwieldy. Instead, try setting the correct port manually in SQL server configuration, and connect with the explicit port.

Comment: in addition to it we can set static port for the named instance. That might help

Comment: yep.. i already set the port in ssql server configuration to static.. still not working

Comment: @user3283259 And have you setup port forwarding on both of the ports? And are you connecting with an explicit port specified? Also, make sure that the firewall on the server isn't blocking the connection.